# git core.hooksPath permission denied issue

Tags: git, githooks

I'm trying to have one repo with all my githooks and every other repo references that.

My repo directory structure looks like this.

```
~/dev/githooks/.git/hooks
 |-> pre-push
   |-> prevent-master
```

`prevent-master`

```
#!/bin/sh

branch_blocked="master"

if grep -q "$branch_blocked"; then
    echo "Branch '$branch_blocked' is blocked by yourself." >&2
    exit 1
fi
```

Now I tell my git config to use this githook directory `git config core.hooksPath ~/dev/githooks/.git/hooks`

In a separate repo I'm trying to push and it says

```
clickthisnick$ git push
fatal: cannot exec '/Users/clickthisnick/dev/githooks/.git/hooks/pre-push': Permission denied
```

I have `chmod -R +xr ~/dev/githooks` and am using a git version that supports this `git version 2.17.2`.

Anything else I can try to get this to work?

Comment: The path that you `chmod`ed is not the path to your hooks (`~/dev/githooks.git` vs `~/dev/githooks/.git`)...

Comment: Good catch, that was a typo tho. I chmod the correct directory and its parent

Comment: What's the output of `ls -l /Users/clickthisnick/dev/githooks/.git/hooks/pre-push`?

Comment: `-rwxr-xr-x  1 clickthisnick  staff  149 Jan  2 15:02 prevent-master`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your git hook needs to be an *executable file*, not a directory.  git will try to invoke:

```
/Users/clickthisnick/dev/githooks/.git/hooks/pre-push
```

But you have this configured as a directory, containing a hook (`prevent-master`) not a file.  Instead, rename:

```
/Users/clickthisnick/dev/githooks/.git/hooks/pre-push/prevent-master
```

to

```
/Users/clickthisnick/dev/githooks/.git/hooks/pre-push
```